# Select row by id and it's nearest rows sorted by some value. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have chapters table like this:

```
id | title    | sort_number | book_id
1  | 'Chap 1' | 3           | 1
5  | 'Chap 2' | 6           | 1
8  | 'About ' | 1           | 1
9  | 'Chap 3' | 9           | 1
10 | 'Attack' | 1           | 2
```

Id is unique, sort_number is unique for same book(book_id)

1)How can load all data (3 rows) for 3 chapters (current, next and prev) sorted by sort_number if i have only current chapter id?

2)How can i load current chapter data (1 row) and only id's of next, prev if they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

```
select id, title, sort_number, book_id, 
       lag(id) over w as prev_chapter,
       lead(id) over w as next_chapter
from chapters
window w as (partition by book_id order by sort_number);
```

With your sample data that returns:

```
id | title  | sort_number | book_id | prev_chapter | next_chapter
---+--------+-------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 8 | About  |           1 |       1 |              |            1
 1 | Chap 1 |           3 |       1 |            8 |            5
 5 | Chap 2 |           6 |       1 |            1 |            9
 9 | Chap 3 |           9 |       1 |            5 |             
10 | Attack |           1 |       2 |              |
```

The above query can now be used to answer both your questions:

1)

```
select id, title, sort_number, book_id
from (
  select id, title, sort_number, book_id, 
         --first_value(id) over w as first_chapter,
         lag(id) over w as prev_chapter_id,
         lead(id) over w as next_chapter_id
  from chapters
  window w as (partition by book_id order by sort_number)
) t
where 1 in (id, prev_chapter_id, next_chapter_id)
```

2)

```
select *
from (
  select id, title, sort_number, book_id, 
         lag(id) over w as prev_chapter_id,
         lead(id) over w as next_chapter_id
  from chapters
  window w as (partition by book_id order by sort_number)
) t
where id = 1
```