# Select a specific row with the following rows sorted by some value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with id and value:

```
id value
1  30
2  20
3  10
4  50
5  30
6  40
```

I want to select a row by id with the following rows sorted by value. If multiple rows have the same value, sort them by id. Technically, it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476097/select-row-by-id-and-its-nearest-rows-sorted-by-some-value-postgresql), with the difference that not only the nearest row, but also more.

For example, row with id = 2 with the following three rows:

```
id value
2  20
1  30
5  30
6  40
```

I know there are window functions for this, but I don't know which ones to use.

Comment: What constitutes *following*?  What caused ids 3,4 to drop out of the results but kept id 1? Please update your question.

Comment: @Belayer please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476097/select-row-by-id-and-its-nearest-rows-sorted-by-some-value-postgresql) is very similar. If I did not formulate it correctly, feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
with CTE
as
(
select distinct value from tab order by 1
)
select * from tab where value in (select * from cte where value >= (select value from tab where id=2 ) limit 3) ;
```

**Edit 1**:
SQL:

```
with CTE
as
(
select distinct value from tab order by 1
)
Select * from (select * from tab where value in (select * from cte where value > (select value from tab where id=5 ))  limit 3) subq 
union all
select * from tab where id=5;
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62b3de8e2910f15556fe136dc7abf61b)

Comment: This works except situation if you want to select the first row that has the same value as the other. In my example, when you select from row id 5, you also get id 1, which is unwanted.

Comment: Good Catch! I have modified the SQL which is in the new Edit , verified output in dbfiddle link.